# Using Supabase CLI within Docker Image

Tags: docker, supabase

I installed Supabase in a docker container using these instructions:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker

Now, I want to generate TypeScript types for my database. Apparently, this is possible via the Supabase CLI.

How would I use the CLI within a docker container?

When I run `docker compose exec studio /bin/bash` and then `npx supabase help`, I get this error: `npm ERR! could not determine executable to run`.

Comment: Seems off-topic, because not about programming

Comment: @Vega I do need this for my code to work as I'm programming in TypeScript and I can't use my database without it lol.

Comment: Coffee machine is also important for programmers

Comment: On the serious note, this is devops, thus off-topic on SO. Try on an other dedicated SE site

Comment: @Vega well, DevOps doesn't have a supabase tag, how are people supposed to find this question then? :)

Comment: Super User and Servers fault are more appropiated

Comment: in all cases, this is off-topic, as I said, whatever your criteria are